# How many kWh this turbine would generate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, control-engineering, hydraulics, turbines

My grandfather and I are running some experiments down the river, however we don't have expertise in engineering so I bring up this question to the community and hope someone could help.

How many kWh a turbine with the following features would generate?

[image: Just a simple prototype]
[image: Just a simple prototype]

These images are just a simple prototype which does not apply some of the following features:

Shape: Reel.

Length: 1.50m.

Diameter: 1.20m. (Including its palettes and axis which has the thickness of 20cm.)

10 Longitudinal/helical palettes with length of 1.50m., thickness of 2cm. and height of 50cm.

Total weight: 50kg. (Palettes and axis included for torque boost.)

Flow rate (amount flowing through the device): 3m³/s

River conditions:

Flow rate: 209.000 m³/s

Speed: 2 meters per second.

Depth: 40m.

It would be installed 2 meters beneath the river surface, placed horizontally.

Comment: Power developed won’t be from the flow of the whole river but the amount flowing through the device. Check out water wheel calculations...

Comment: this question was already answered on the physics stack exchange.

Comment: @nielsnielsen According to your answer on the physics stack exchange I did update my question with the Flow rate condition as you can see, by the way my question on the physics stack exchange has been closed because they suggested me to recreate a new one on the engineering stack exchange, so I did it.

Comment: kWh is a unit of energy. You want to know power, or kW.

Comment: @Hearth kW the unit of energy itself

Comment: @SolarMike I did update my question with the proper flow rate that flows through the device as you pointed out.

Comment: No, @Rafa. Energy = power x time. The unit of **power** (for this exercise) is the kW and the unit of **energy** is the kWh. The energy produced per hour is P x t = kW x h = kWh. Understanding this is important for your project.

Comment: It seems to me that you can eliminate all the drag of the convex sections moving against the flow by mounting the device on the surface with the axle horizontal and at surface level. That way the returning "pallettes" are only resisted by air.

Comment: Did you check out water wherl calculations? Transistor has pointed you to the same... undershot, breastshot and overshot are worth checking.

Comment: @Transistor Since there's more water pressure at the depth of 10 meters for example, a turbine at surface level would have more power than a turbine at a deeper level such as 10 meters beneath the river surface?

Comment: @SolarMike I did check that and it helped me to clear out my thoughts, but still a doubt as you can see in my previous comment directed to Transistor.

Comment: Did you think that the water pressure will be different or the same for both sides of the turbine whatever the depth?

Comment: @Rafa, water is incompressible. You are planning to have your device underwater so, as Mike says, the pressure will be the same on both sides. You will have terrible drag on the return side. The depth matters when you have "head" - difference in height between input and output because you have a difference in potential energy. With your system you are trying to extract energy from the momentum of the water. I think you need to do more research to gain understanding. If the flow rates are the same it doesn't matter if you put your device at 10 m or 1 m but half-submerged would be much better.